# connecting android emulator as a physical android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio and I am emulating a device and I need is for the emulated device to e shown on my computer as if it was connected physically ... there is an on my pc I need to see my emulator as USB android so when it works I can use it on my actual device.

Comment: you want to use actual device for android studio right?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you want to attach a physical device and debug on that?  Or do you want to change how the android emulator works somehow?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right...

but if you want to connect your physical phone to run your application you need to make these steps.

First thing first you have to activate android developer mode on your phone, to do that
go to your phone settings click on 'about phone', tap on "software information" and then scroll down to 'build number' and tap it 7 times.
after you'll see a popup message saying that you activated developer mode.
(here is a link in case you didn't understand https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-turn-on-the-developer-options-menu-on-my-samsung-galaxy-device/)

after that go back to main settings go scroll down to the bottom and there you will see "developer options" [image: developer options image]

tap on it and it will transfer you to the options then go to the wireless debugging [image: wireless debugging image]

and turn it on and click it.
after you clicked you will be transferred to this page [image: wireless debugging options]

you can choose either one of them.

now in android studio [image]

Click the Pair device using wifi (you should be on the same network to use it)
and choose what you would like to use
[image]

and that's it...
Unfourtonaly USB debugging doesn't work for me.